# TypeError: canvas.selectAll(...).data(...).enter is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I wrote the code below and took most of it from a tutorial online.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>D3</title>
    <script src = "https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
</head>

<body>
    <script>    
    d3.csv("CSV_Data\2006_Sport-in-Bayern - Men.csv", function(data) {
        var width = 1000;
        var height = 1000;  
        var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                    .attr("width", width)
                    .attr("height", height)
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(200, 100)");

        canvas.selectAll("rect")
            .data(data) 
            .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("width", 25)
                .attr("height", function (d) {return d.bis_5_Jahre * 10; })
                .attr("x", function (d, i) {return i * 30; })
                .attr("fill", "blue")
    })      
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Some answers to similar questions were implying typing errors or not putting data before  `.enter` or a missing comma in the csv file. In my case non of those is wrong. I can't seem to find the cause for this error.

EDIT: Here is the Link of the created Plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/iWBymzvCTUMj8LN7xhDV?p=preview

Some CSV rows:

```
Sportart;bis_5_Jahre;6_13;14 - 17;18 - 26;27 - 40;41 - 60;ab 61 Jahre
Aikido;90;1254;443;484;1065;955;115
American Football;7;205;696;1391;1058;271;19
Badminton;62;2121;2144;2575;4650;4961;550
Base- u. Softball;92;602;409;476;706;217;30
Basketball;170;6430;6321;6577;4291;3412;589
...
```

Comment: This code doesn't give that error. Please create a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/) with your code and the CSV. Plunker is a nice editor because you can reproduce your CSV file (click "add new file").

Comment: Thank you @Gerardo Furtado. I tried to put the code in the plunker and run it, it creates the canvas but the data does not appear. How do i make sure the csv file is linked correctly?

Comment: Please, share that plunker in your question (click "edit" and add the link). You have to copy/paste the CSV content when you create a "new file" in the plunker. Otherwise, simply copy/paste a few rows of your CSV in the question, it will help as well.

Comment: I did create a new file and copied the CSV content into it. In the edit you see the link to the plunker.

Comment: Well, I can't see the CSV in that plunker. In the plunker, click "new file" on the left panel and copy your CSV. Alternatively, as I said, simply copy some roes of your CSV in the question itself.

Comment: Sorry i hadn't saved the session. https://plnkr.co/edit/iWBymzvCTUMj8LN7xhDV?p=preview

Comment: Well, your problem is very simple: CSV means **comma** separated values. Your CSV is not valid. Thus, change all `;` for `,`. Here is the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/fNYWl73WvyYrerGdOqyk?p=preview

Comment: Sorry to bother you that much, but i'm not used to work with html, js or data visualizing. I did as you said but still get Bad Request. :/

Comment: That's a problem in the plunker site, the server is facing some issue. But your issue is just this, changing the semicolon for a comma!

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try again later to see if it works or i will try to connect with a server to run it on the browser as i've seen suggested in some posts.